Swagger Support for Apache Camel 4
I am upgrading from Apache Camel 3.20.x to 4.x.x and found that camel-swagger-java(version 3.20.x) which was supported with Camel 3 isn't supported with Camel 4. The camel-swagger-java library hasn't been upgraded to 4.x.x like camel and the latest version available is only 3.22.1.
Some of the methods in CamelContext class(present in camel-api dependency) like getExtension which were available in 3.20.x and are invoked in RestSwaggerSupport class( present in camel-swagger-java) appear deprecated in CamelContext class with Camel 4.x.x versions due to which I am getting NoSuchMethodError.
Issue is occurring as using the same 3.20.x version in camel-swagger-java with Camel 4.x.x Is there a way to make it work with the Camel 4 upgrade?
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object org.apache.camel.CamelContext.getExtension(java.lang.Class)'
at org.apache.camel.swagger.RestSwaggerSupport.getRestDefinitions(RestSwaggerSupport.java:133)


Are you maybe looking for camel-openapi-java?
It was supported since Camel 3.1 and continues to be supported in 4.x - When you were used to Swagger 2.x you can see OpenAPI a bit like the successor of Swagger, but this blog entry describes it a bit better:

The easiest way to understand the difference is:

OpenAPI = Specification
Swagger = Tools for implementing the specification


So the camel component provides the OpenAPI description of your REST interface, but Swagger UI is a tool to display it in the browser and make sample requests etc.
